# loop and put array within array according to id failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

http://jsfiddle.net/rw0z9e2j/

```
var sports = [{
    "id": 1,
        "name": "baseball"
}, {
    "id": 2,
        "name": "Football"
}];

var playersData = [{
    "sport_id": 2,
        "id": "nv12",
        "name": "James"
}, {
    "sport_id": 2,
        "id": "nv11",
        "name": "Jean"
}];

var arr = [],
    tempObj = {};

$.each(sports, function (i, obj) {
    var sport_id = obj.id;

    $.each(playersData, function (i, obj) {
        if (sport_id == obj.sport_id) {
            tempObj = {
                "sport_id": obj.sport_id,
                    "id": obj.id,
                    "name": obj.name
            };
            arr.push(tempObj);
        }

    });
    obj.players = arr;
});

console.log(sports);
```

I try to build an array of players and put them within sports group according to sport_id but above logic has failed. **It didn't group properly,  the player who's in sport_id = 1 should go to sport which its id = 1 but why it didn't?**

what's wrong with above loop there?

Comment: please post a wanted result

Comment: @NinaScholz the player who's in sport_id = 1 should go to sport which its id = 1.

Comment: you habe `obj` twice, as well as `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring your temp `vars` outside of your loops, these should be scoped to your loops and thrown away after each operation.

```
var arr = [],
    tempObj = {};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samternent/rw0z9e2j/2/

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this is what you want:

```js
var sports = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "baseball"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Football"
}];

var playersData = [{
    "sport_id": 2,
    "id": "nv12",
    "name": "James"
}, {
    "sport_id": 2,
    "id": "nv11",
    "name": "Jean"
}];

sports.forEach(function (a) {
    var arr = [];
    playersData.forEach(function (b) {
        if (a.id == b.sport_id) {
            arr.push(b);
        }
    });
    a.players = arr;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(sports, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Where is my problem mate?

Comment: can u take a look at Jai's answer below, he need not to clear the arr.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put it after push:

```
arr.push(tempObj);
obj.players = arr;
```

---

Actually you need this:

```js
var sports = [{
    "id": 1,
        "name": "baseball"
}, {
    "id": 2,
        "name": "Football"
}];

var playersData = [{
    "sport_id": 2,
        "id": "nv12",
        "name": "James"
}, {
    "sport_id": 2,
        "id": "nv11",
        "name": "Jean"
}];

var arr = [];

$.each(sports, function (i, obj) {
    $.each(playersData, function (i, player) {
        if (obj.id === player.sport_id) {
           var tempObj = {
                "sport_id": player.sport_id,
                    "id": player.id,
                    "name": player.name
            };
            arr.push(tempObj);
            obj.players = arr;
        }

    });
    
});

console.log(sports);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this doesn't work, obj.players will refer to the playersData as it's in the $.each loop.

Comment: i have changed the arguments name for readability you can see first one in the each is `obj` and in second each is `player` instead of `obj`. so `obj.players` actually referring to the first one.

Comment: can u help to take a look here? http://jsfiddle.net/2sn9vk2a/ it doesn't work, I tried to follow ur logic.

Comment: you can check your data if they have proper keys in it and i guess you need to ask to the person whose answer you have accepted.

Comment: both of your code worked, but I don't know what's the different, and which one has better performaces.

Comment: actually I just found out that your code doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/rh8h6x69/

Answer (score 0):

Hope you want to put inside the Sports group, but you are adding inside the player array, please notice, so please  call

```
obj.sports = arr;
```

Hope it solve your problem .